# Fortran indexing

Tags: fortran, fortran95

I'm currently trying to run diagnostics on a rather lenghty code. I can't see why the following snippet does not print what I expect it to print. `QR_W` is a three-dimensional matrix.

```
print*, 'max val in QR_W is', maxval(QR_W), ' at ', maxloc(QR_W) 
print*, QR_W(4,2,5)
```

prints out

```
max val in QR_W is   31180.3061633961       at            4           2           5
0.000000000000000E+000
```

EDIT: As RussF suggested, the unintuitive result is caused by how QR_W is defined. The first index in QR_W was zero. Adding an offset of one to the (e.g. in this case Q_RW(3,1,4)) solved the problem.

Comment: How is `qr_w` declared?

Comment: Welcome. It looks surprising indeed. To be able to identify what is going on we need to see more code (see [mcve]), because it is not something one would expect.

Comment: `maxloc` returns the location of the maximum in a range `1` to`n` where `n` is the extent of each dimension. i.e. if your lower bounds are not 1 then you need to apply an offset of `lbound(QR_W)-1` to the location.